# Unusual Tournament spot

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, live, all-in, hand

Ok this was when I first started playing so please go easy on me, live tournament 80 players down to 13, paid at 7th
 8 handed
blinds are 1500/3000
Hero (120,000 ) average stack
V1 (250,000)
V2/V3 (20,000 ish)

V3 LP jams blind, V2 EP jams pre, V1  EP flats the 20k, Hero Button (AQs) 3bets to 64k (mistake 1). Folds backs to V1 who says let’s gamble and pushes all of his chips in saying I’ll call, thinking I’m all in, them he shows (A10s) so now he realizes I’m not all in and I’ve got 60k behind, so now the side pot is massive and I call? I’m certain I should’ve either ripped it in pre or just folded? But there’s no way I can fold that spot

Comment: Can you add positions of the players? How big was the table?

Comment: Added sorry, we were 8handed I was on the button V1 was EP as was V2, V3 was CO but he already jammed before cards were dealt

Comment: were there antes in play?

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AQs is not a premium hand but you are getting 3:1 on a call. The short stacks have a big range. The big stack just flatting is odd. Either they have a monster and want a call or are just taking a chance with a speculative hand on busting out two players. I would just call in that spot hoping to improve on the flop. You are going to hit a 4 flush, A, or Q like 30%.  If you don't improve on the flop and V1 bets you can just fold. 20K is a big investment but you have a chance to knock out 2 and more than triple up.  By just raising pre you give the big stack a chance to push and put you in a tough spot.  If you shove pre you still are still facing two all in and a only a better hand will call.  This is a call for me.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely shouldn't 3-bet. The way I see it, you have two options; fold, call or shove. I lean towards a fold. Especially 8-handed without any antes. Your hand is simply not strong enough to risk 40BB with this action. However, shoving is not unreasonable. If your opponents are loose enough, for example geting called by ATs, AQs might be good enough.

Having 3-bet, V1 shoves. Now you obviously have to call.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, looking back I think I would’ve jammed on the big stack when he flatted, cheers